# Cant add module to my own hook

Tags: hook, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a problem since three different modules are in the same hook. I've made some new hooks so I could separete the modules, but the problem is that I can't add the modules position to my new hooks. When I click on the modules I can only choose like five or six default hooks. Can anyone help? :)

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: There isn't really any code since it just takes place in the prestashop backend

Comment: You didn't create the method for the new hook in the modules?

Answer (score 0):

Add it manually in the table `ps_hook`. Then it will appear in hook positions in backend.